# Marketing Cloud - Landing Page Unsecure

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am trying to build a simple landing page in Marketing Cloud.

While creating the landing page, I used our private domain and ensured the "HTTPS" is checked as shown below

[image]

But when I clicked on the landing page URL (after saving and publishing it), I am getting a"not secure" warning

[image]

Can someone let me know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't have the SSL certificate for the Cloudpage.

The SSL certificate isn't included in the SAP package therefore whenever we create a MC page using the private domain, it will show the Not Secure error.

To fully secure MC's Images/Links/Pages, you may need **2**x SSL: 1 for Cloud Pages/Clicks/Views, and 1 for image URLs and it can be purchased through MC Account Executive

Reference: [SSL Certificates for Account Branding](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_ssl_certificates.htm&type=5)